# Do you have to use gradle-experimental for JNI?

Tags: android, android-ndk

All the NDK JNI tutorials I read, including the ones from Google instructs me to replace the gradle dependency with the experimental version. Is this still necessary?

[Google's guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2) also says to put the `ndk {}` block under the `buildTypes` block but that fails for me and the only thing that seems to work is putting it in the `defaultConfig` block. However, the guide also says that I should be able to generate JNI methods by using the context menu when defining native functions. This doesnt work for me.

So do I still have to use experimental gradle for JNI? Seems odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these are old manuals. Since AS 2.2, you can use cmake or ndk-build. See https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Comment: Thanks. Really wish Google would clean up their documentation and remove old legacy stuff.